# Material Design - Persistent search, with navigation drawer

Tags: android, material-design

Is this within the guidelines or do you at least think it's an acceptable practice?

I'd like to use a persistent search bar, but my app necessitates a navigation drawer. I feel like it might be a bit weird to have the hamburger button and a search bar in a toolbar at the same time.

Comment: Short answer: yes.  http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/toolbars.html#toolbars-usage (See Do's)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's within the guidelines. The Google and Play Store apps both show the hamburger button inside the search bar.

[image: search bar in Google Now]

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is within the guidelines and would be an acceptable practice. I have included two examples of what you could do as well as the example that @tehShane provided.

**Example 1**

You could extend the toolbar to include a persistent search bar like the example below. With the new Toolbar widget it is very easy to customise and extend your toolbar to suit your needs.

[image: Persistent Search in the Toolbar]

**Example 2**

You could have a persistent search bar that is anchored just below the toolbar like the example below.

[image: Persistent Search below the Toolbar]

Another approach would be to use a [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ie.iamshanedoyle.craftbeers) is an example of an app that uses a SearchView in the toolbar.

Either way it would be perfectly acceptable practice, of course you would want to test which solution is best for your app and your users.

Comment: Where can I get this kind of widget as in your first two examples?